# C# using register

Tags: c#, c++

I have C++ code that I want to convert to C# code. But I don't know how to use `register` keyword in C#. How can I convert to C# following code?

```
int InsertNode(register Node **linkp, Node * inserted_node)
{
    register Node *current;

    while ((current = *linkp) != NULL && current->value > inserted_node->value)
    {
        linkp = &current->link;
    }

    inserted_node->link = current;
    *linkp = inserted_node;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `C` code you posted uses the `register` keyword to attempt to force a particular optimization on the compiler.  This doesn't change anything about the way the code works, only about how the compiler generates the machine code that will ultimately run on the CPU.

The reality is that this sort of compiler hinting is largely unnecessary with modern compilers, and can actually reduce the efficiency of the output code as it juggles to try to accommodate your demands that a particular piece of information be kept on the CPU.  Optimizers are smart enough these days to figure out what does and doesn't need to be on the CPU, we can trust them that far most of the time.

As for `C#` though... there is no compatible concept.  There are also no safe pointers, so you'll have to get rid of those.  Just use references instead, they work find for linked lists.

Try this:

```
public class LinkedList<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public class Node
    {
        public Node link;
        public T value;
    }

    public Node root = null;


    public bool InsertValue(T value)
    {
        return InsertNode(new Node { value = value });
    }

    public bool InsertNode(Node inserted_node)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = inserted_node;
            return true;
        }
        Node prev = null;
        Node current = root;
        while (current != null && current.value.CompareTo(inserted_node.value) > 0)
        {
            prev = current;
            current = current.link;
        }

        prev.link = inserted_node;
        inserted_node.link = current;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new LinkedList<int>();
    list.InsertValue(5);
    list.InsertValue(2);
    list.InsertValue(3);

    for (var c = list.root; c != null; c = c.link)
        Console.WriteLine(c.value);
}
```

Comment: Of course you could just use the built-int [`LinkedList<T>` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yeah, but it's instructive to build your own versions of these things sometimes.  Knowing how this stuff works is actually useful :)

Comment: Sure, I was giving a hint, just in case. I guess the C++ code could have been written with [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) too. :)

Answer (score 0):

`register` does nothing in C++. In C it is a hint to compiler to place variable in register, which it can ignore.

You can just throw away `register` keyword. I would be surprised if it changes anything in resulting binary.